# BQ29700: Problem with the battery protection

Tags: batteries, protection

this is my first post here!

I have a problem with a custom board I made.

The problem is when I plug the battery nothing happens, no voltage flow, but if I touch the VBAT- with GND of my PCB for a instant, the voltage is OK all the time, the current flow and the battery works properly.

3.7 V battery Li-Ion 1 cell

Any idea are welcome!

[image: Here you can see my battery protection]

Answer (score 1):

On the page 18 of the ds:http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq2970.pdf

> When the battery is connected for the first time, the discharging
>   circuit might not be enabled. In this case, short the V– pin to the
>   VSS pin. Alternatively, connect the charger between the Pack+ and Pack
>   – terminals in the system.